# Mac safari open a URL in new tab/window using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, safari

The requirement is I get URL of excel file in webservice response. I want to open this URL in new tab/window using javascript.

```
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

doesn't work in mac safari.

I also tried creating `<a>` with target="_blank" and trigger click.But it didn't work with Mac safari.

Is there any way to achieve the requirement?
Open the excel file in some specific div will also serve if it is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: window.open doesnt work in safari. the only way is window.location

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a popup blocker installed ? if yes then read this . Safari/Chrome have built-in pop-up blockers that stop this from working. The only javascript that is allowed to open a new window in Safari/Chrome is javascript directly attached to click handlers (and other direct user input handlers). In past versions people figured out some ways to cheat (like generating some other element -- a form or div -- and simulating user input with javascript), but newer versions are smarter about detecting this. I'd recommend re-configuring things so that you don't use a delayed pop-up -- that is the kind of thing that can generally be jarring to a user after all.

Comment: I am aware about that this is not working and blocked and all the reasons behind that... I am searching for the posibilities to achieve this...is there any other way to achieve this?? or open the excel from the URL in specific div so that it doesn't cover the current screen??

Comment: Once try this .``var myWin = window.open([args]);

if (myWin == undefined)
   alert('Please disable your popup blocker');``

Comment: use this ``<div class='btn' onclick='window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank");'>Open google search</div>``

Comment: 1. I am getting URL in webservice and need to open it as soon as I recevie the response. I can not ask user to click.  2.I already mentioned, window.open doesnt work in mac safari. refernece: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs.html

Comment: Then you can use this from the reference. ``var newTab = safari.self.browserWindow.openTab();``

Comment: I can not use this directly... I need to create an extention to use this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114913/discussion-between-rittam-and-mitali).